# PHP - Simpletest - How to test "included" classes

Tags: php, testing, case, simpletest

I have de follow code:

```
include 'simpletest/autorun.php';
include 'config_test.case.php'; // <-- problem
```

But it not works. I get:

```
Bad TestSuite [index.php] with error [No runnable test cases in [index.php]]
```

But if I put the Config class code directly (no "include"), it works.
What can I do?
Thx =)

Comment: Is `config_test.case.php` in the same folder as the script that's running?

Comment: No. config_test.case.php is in a different folder than index.php (where is included auturun.php)

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you have the correct path to your test cases.

I also use the PHP autoLoader() function to auto-magically resolve my own class paths so they don't need to be inclcuded in the paths.

Comment: That is only a temporary solution, until I have the classes I need to create the MVC e organize everything in your place. Until then, what can I do to the tests work that way (or similar)?